# Profile picture URL using http://graph.facebook.com/{social network id}/picture?type=large not returning profile pic actual profile picture

Tags: facebook, profile-picture

For getting profile picture if we are using the graph api url, its returning the avatar image but not the actual profile picture of the user.

http://graph.facebook.com/{social network id}/picture?type=large

Comment: I'm having the same issue ?

Comment: @gunjotsingh as do countless other people, the page with the current questions under the `facebook` tag is overflowing with this right now. Going “me too, me too!!!1” here isn’t going to resolve this any faster. Subscribe to the relevant bugs reports if you want Facebook to prioritize this more.

Comment: Just noticed on Facebook and subscribed. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/ Thank you